# Graph Theory: number of connected triples

Tags: networking, graph

In order to find the Global Clustering Coefficient I need to find the number of connected triples. About this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYTbf.png):

these are the triples that I found:

1. 7-6-5
2. 5-3-7
3. 5-3-1
4. 4-3-7
5. 4-3-1
6. 4-5-6
7. 3-7-6
8. 3-5-6
9. 2-3-4
10. 2-1-7
11. 2-3-5
12. 1-7-6

total: 12 triples.

Moreover, there are 3 triangles, and 1 triangle is equal to 3 triples. So in total there are 12 + 3*3 = 21 triples. Is that correct? And is it possible to find a rule or a method to find all the connected triples in a graph without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

summation of k*(k-1)/2, where k is the degree of all nodes.